# Responsive CSS (My topmenu position is incorrect in some width screen)?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-lists, responsive

I'm new to CSS and responsive designing.

I have an index page that has header, top menu, maintext and footer. The top menu up to 300px is fine but when it goes under 300px, it does not change, and only the additional links to the menus are moved down.

For each media query, I set the color for the maintext and the topmenu temporarily to see how they change when the page width changes.

Where is my mistake?

Or does the insertion of media queries require a specific arrangement to apply changes to screen with a width less than 300 pixels?

Can you check the topmenu in index and css style in media queries?

### My Index page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=4">
<title>registering system</title>
<link href="style-en.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--<link href="refer/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

<script src="ref/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="" >


<div id="top">
              <div class="topmenu" id="topmenu" >
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php">Main Page</a></li>
                              <?php if(!(isset($_SESSION["username"]))) { ?>
                               <li><a href="index.php?click=ln">Sign in</a></li>
                               <?php } ?>

                                <li><a href="index.php?click=contact">contact us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?click=req">request</a></li><br>
                                <li><a href="index.php?click=regp">register person</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?click=regc">register in classes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?click=lp">List of persons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?click=lc"></a>List of classes</li>
                                <?php if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) { ?><li><a id="logout"  href="index.php?click=logout">logout</a></li> <?php } //logout can be this : index.php?click=logout?>

                            </ul>
              </div>

    <div  id="header" style=" background-color:#003;opacity:0.6;text-align: center" >
        <font>
            Registering System Of Education Center
        </font>
    </div>
<div class="logo" id="logo1"  align="center" >



 </div>


</div>

<div id="wrap" >
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div id="main" align="right">
   <?php if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) { ?>

    <?php 
          }

   $connect=$link=db_conncet2();
    $click=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_GET["click"]);


    ?>
        <a name="bl1"></a>
    <?php
    if(!($click=="ln") ) {

        if (!($click=="recov")) {
            $dv="1";
         ?>

    <?php
        }

    } 
    if(!($click=="recov") ) {

        if (!($click=="ln")) {
            if(!($dv=="1")){
         ?>

    <?php
            }
        }

    } ?>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <div id="maintext">
<?php   


        if($click=="ln")
            {



                require_once("login.php");

            }

        elseif($click=="logout")
        {
            require_once("logout.php");

        }



            else
            { ?>
    <p style="width:700px"><strong style="font-size:24px">Information:</strong><br />This is main page...</p>



            <?php } ?>
      </div>


</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <div id="footerbg" style=" background-color:#003;opacity:0.6;" >



       </div> 

          <div id="info">

            <table id="tblfooternormal" style="bottom:0px;right:0;min-width:700px;" >
                  <tr>
                      <td width="25px"></td>

                      <td>

                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:100px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />

                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:100px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:100px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:100px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>

                      </td>
                      <td>        <img src="img/telegram.png" width="50px" height="50px" style=" clear:left;

float:right;margin-left:20px; " /><font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>Our channel:</b></font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b><a href="http://#" target="_blank"

                                                                 style="text-decoration: none;color:#09C;" >####</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font><br />
                      </td>

                      <td>
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px

solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px

solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br

                          />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>Address:</b></font><br /><br />

                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>Tel:</b></font><br />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px

solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px

solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br

                          />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>Wrb design department</b></font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>History:</b></font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>.................</b></font><br />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br

                          />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br

                          />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br

                          />
                          <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                      </td>

                  </tr>

              </table>
              <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////responsive table//////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
              <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////responsive table//////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
              <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////responsive table//////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

              <table id="tblfooterrespons"  style="bottom:0px;right:10px;width: 70%;" >
                  <tr style="width: 50%">


                      <td>
                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>Wrb design department</b></font><br />


                          <img src="img/telegram.png" width="50px" height="50px" style=" clear:left;

float:right;margin-left:20px; " /><font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>Our channel:</b></font><br />
                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b><a href="http://#" target="_blank"

                                                                 style="text-decoration: none;color:#09C;" >###</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font><br />
                      </td></tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>

                          <hr color="#00CC66" >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>

                      <td>
                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>Address:</b></font><br /><br />

                          <font color="#00CC66" id="down" ><b>Tel:</b></font><br />
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>

                          <hr color="#00CC66" >

                      </td>
                  </tr>

              </table>
        </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

### And my CSS style is this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'headfont';
    src: url('fonts/headfontBd.eot');src: url('fonts/headfontBd.eot?#') format('eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/headfontBd.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/headfontBd.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/headfontBd.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'containfont';
    src: url('fonts/containfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/containfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/containfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/containfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

* {margin:0;padding:0;}




html, body {

    height: 100%;
    /*max-width: inherit;*/

    direction:rtl;
    font-family:"containfont",Tahoma, Arial;
    background-image:url(bg/bg7-2.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    /*background-position-x: -210px;*/
    /*background-position-y: -415px;*/
    background-size: 150%,150%;
    }

#wrap {
     min-height: 100%;

     }

#main {

    padding-bottom: 210px;
    padding-right:20px;
    min-height:150px;
    min-width:550px;


    }  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 100px;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    } 
    #top 
    {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -100px; /* negative value of top height */
    height: 100px;
    clear:both;
    /*min-width:80em;*/


    }
#tblfooterrespons
{
    display: none;
}



 #topmenu ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align:center;

}


#topmenu li {
    margin-right:1em;
    float: right;
    outline-width:medium;  
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -o-border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    background-color:#069;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 122px;

}
#topmenu {

    padding-top:5em;
    max-height:25px;
    min-height:25px;
    /*width:70em;*/
    opacity:1;
    margin-right:0em;
    z-index: 1000;

    position:absolute;

}

#topmenu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 26px;

    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -o-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;

    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;


}


li a:hover {
    background-color: #18E9F3;
    color:#000 !important;
}


a:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
}
a:link { text-decoration:none; border:none }




#header,#logo1
{
    top:0em;
    left:0em;



}

#header
{
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    /*font-size: larger;*/
    font-family: headfont;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header font
{
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #00ffff;
    text-align: center;
}
#header,#logo1,#footerbg,#info
{
    width: 100%;
    /*min-width:100%;*/
     /*or 100%*/

    z-index: 14;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin:0px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    }
#footerbg,#info
{
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    /*min-height:115px;*/

    }
    #footerbg
    {

        min-width: 100%;
        min-height:115px;

    }
#info   
{

margin-right: 0px;  /* jadid 97/02 */
}

#down
{
    font-size:14px;

}

#userinfo
 {
     margin-right:52em;
     min-width:200px;
    width:300px;
     height: 150px;
     position:absolute;
    background: #5EFF5E;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;

}

#bgcontainer
 {
     margin-right:13.5em;
     margin-top:-2em;
     padding-bottom:1.25em;
     padding-top:4.25em;
    height:8.25em;
    width:25em;
    background-color:#7DA8FF    ;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

z-idex:2;
    position:absolute;


}
#bgcontainer2
 {
     margin-right:13.5em;
     margin-top:-2em;
     padding-bottom:1.25em;
     padding-top:2.25em;
    height:12em;
    width:25em;
    background-color:#7DA8FF    ;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
     z-idex:2;
    position:absolute;


}
#bgcontainer3
 {

    padding-top:1.5em;
    margin-top:2em;
    margin-right:13.5em;
    text-align:center;
    width:25em;
    background-color:#FFD5D5    ;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    vertical-align:top;
    color:#FF0D13;
    position:relative;

}
#maintext
 {

     padding-right:0%;
     max-width:600px;
     /*width:820px;*/
    /* width:auto;*/
    margin-top: 60px;
     padding-bottom:50px;
    background: #8CE8F2;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
#p1
{
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

#spacer
{
    height:10px !important; 
}
#spacer2
{
    height:40px !important; 
}
input
{

    margin-right:0%;    
}
label
{
margin-right:5%;    
}
p
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top:3%;
    min-height:50px;
    padding-right:5%;
    max-width:500px; /*jadid 97*/
    clear:both;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#8CE8F2;
    margin-left:10%;
    padding-bottom:4%;
    -moz-border-radius:  50px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  50px 0px;
    -o-border-radius:  50px 0px;
    border-radius: 50px 0px;



    }
table,tr
{

    border-spacing: 5px;    
    -moz-border-radius:  20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  20px;
    -o-border-radius:  20px;
    border-radius: 20px;



    }
td
{

    -moz-border-radius:  10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  10px;
    -o-border-radius:  10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
th
{

    -moz-border-radius:  10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  10px;
    -o-border-radius:  10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}


input[dpieagent_iecontroltype="2"]
{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color:#000;
}
input[type="text"]
{
     text-indent: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color:#000;
}
input[type="password"]
{
    text-indent: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color:#000;
}
input[type="submit"]
{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color:#000;
    font-family: containfont, Tahoma, Arial ;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
input[type="reset"]
{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    font-family: containfont, Tahoma, Arial ;
    border-color:#000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
input[type="button"]
{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color:#000;
}
select
{

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color:#000;
    font-family:"containfont",Tahoma, Arial;
}
#exit
{
background-color:#FF4040;
        transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#exit:hover {
    background-color: #FF8040;
    color:#000 !important;
}






@media only screen and (max-device-width : 740px){
    /*#logo {margin: 0 auto;}*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 740px) {
    #header {


        font-family: headfont;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #header font {
        /*size: 26px;*/
        font-size: 26px;
        color: #00ffff;

        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 700px){
    /*#logo {margin: 0 auto;}*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px){

    #footerbg
    {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 200px;

    }
    #footer
    {
        margin-top: -250px;
        height: 250px;
        min-height:250px;
    }
    #tblfooternormal
    {
        display: none;
    }
    #tblfooterrespons
    {
        margin-right: 35px;
        display: inherit;
    }

}

/*
!*responsive css*!
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 570px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 570px) {
    #header {


        font-family: headfont;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #header font {
        /*size: 26px;*/
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #ec4b3f;

        font-weight: bold;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 100px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 100px){
    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%;


    }

}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 200px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 200px){
    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%; 


    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 300px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 300px){

    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%; 


    }
    #header {


        font-family: headfont;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #header font {

        font-size: 16px;
        color: #00ffff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #topmenu {

        padding-top:5em;
        max-height:9px;
        min-height:9px;

        opacity:1;
        margin-right:0em;
        z-index: 1000;

        position:absolute;

    }
    #topmenu li {

        margin-bottom: 10px;
        max-width: 70px;

    }
    #topmenu li a {
        padding: 2px 5px;
        background-color: #ec4b3f;
        font-size: 5px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 400px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px){
    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%; 
        background-color: #ec4b3f;

    }

    #topmenu {

        padding-top:8em;
        max-height:11px;
        min-height:11px;

        opacity:1;
        margin-right:0em;
        z-index: 1000;

        position:absolute;

    }
    #topmenu li {

        margin-bottom: 10px;
        max-width: 90px;

    }
    #topmenu li a {
        padding: 3px 3px;
        background-color: #72F96A;
        font-size: 7px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 500px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 500px){
    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%; 
        background-color: #FF8080;

    }
    #topmenu {

        padding-top:5em;
        max-height:15px;
        min-height:15px;

        opacity:1;
        margin-right:0em;
        z-index: 1000;

        position:absolute;

    }
    #topmenu li {

        margin-bottom: 10px;
        max-width: 125px;

    }

    #topmenu li a {
        padding: 7px 18px;
        background-color: #990099;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 600px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px){
    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%;


    }



    #topmenu li {

        margin-bottom: 10px;
        min-width: 60px;

    }
    #topmenu {



    }

    #topmenu li a {

        font-size: 80%;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 700px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px){
    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%; 


    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 800px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 800px){
    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%; 


    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 900px){
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 900px){
    #main {

        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
    }


    #maintext
    {

        padding-right:0%;
        max-width:90%;
    }
    p
    {
        max-width:80%; 


    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: It's a lot of code, so it's really hard to understand for someone who didn't write it, but I figured out that the problem starts between the 500px and 400px media-queries. At 400px the buttons should turn lime green, and at 300px a soft red, but they stay purple (the color from 500px). I added `#header font {color: white;}` to the 400px media-query and that does change. I just can't figure out why the background and the rest doesn't change. See [**> JSFiddle <**](https://jsfiddle.net/q50y5azu/)

Comment: Why Somone cant help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my fix and suggestion - the only mistake you made is in the ordering of these media queries. I reordered them  from max to min width (say 900 to 100) and everything works. open the below snippet in full screen and it will do as you say.

Hope this helps!!

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'headfont';
    src: url('fonts/headfontBd.eot');
    src: url('fonts/headfontBd.eot?#') format('eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/headfontBd.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/headfontBd.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/headfontBd.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'containfont';
    src: url('fonts/containfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/containfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/containfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/containfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
   /*max-width: inherit;
   */
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: "containfont", Tahoma, Arial;
    background-image: url(bg/bg7-2.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   /*background-position-x: -210px;
   */
   /*background-position-y: -415px;
   */
    background-size: 150%, 150%;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    padding-bottom: 210px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 550px;
}
/* must be same height as the footer */
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px;
   /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
#top {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
   /* negative value of top height */
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
   /*min-width:80em;
   */
}
#tblfooterrespons {
    display: none;
}
#topmenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}
#topmenu li {
    margin-right: 1em;
    float: right;
    outline-width: medium;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -o-border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    background-color: #069;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 122px;
}
#topmenu {
    padding-top: 5em;
    max-height: 25px;
    min-height: 25px;
   /*width:70em;
   */
    opacity: 1;
    margin-right: 0em;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
}
#topmenu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -o-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #18E9F3;
    color: #000 !important;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none 
}
#header, #logo1 {
    top: 0em;
    left: 0em;
}
#header {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
   /*font-size: larger;
   */
    font-family: headfont;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header font {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #00ffff;
    text-align: center;
}
#header, #logo1, #footerbg, #info {
    width: 100%;
   /*min-width:100%;
   */
   /*or 100%*/
    z-index: 14;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
#footerbg, #info {
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
   /*min-height:115px;
   */
}
#footerbg {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 115px;
}
#info {
    margin-right: 0px;
   /* jadid 97/02 */
}
#down {
    font-size: 14px;
}
#userinfo {
    margin-right: 52em;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #5EFF5E;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
#bgcontainer {
    margin-right: 13.5em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
    padding-top: 4.25em;
    height: 8.25em;
    width: 25em;
    background-color: #7DA8FF;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    z-idex: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
#bgcontainer2 {
    margin-right: 13.5em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
    padding-top: 2.25em;
    height: 12em;
    width: 25em;
    background-color: #7DA8FF;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    z-idex: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
#bgcontainer3 {
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-right: 13.5em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25em;
    background-color: #FFD5D5;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #FF0D13;
    position: relative;
}
#maintext {
    padding-right: 0%;
    max-width: 600px;
   /*width:820px;
   */
   /* width:auto;
   */
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: #8CE8F2;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
#p1 {
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
#spacer {
    height: 10px !important;
}
#spacer2 {
    height: 40px !important;
}
input {
    margin-right: 0%;
}
label {
    margin-right: 5%;
}
p {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 3%;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding-right: 5%;
    max-width: 500px;
   /*jadid 97*/
    clear: both;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #8CE8F2;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px 0px;
    border-radius: 50px 0px;
}
table, tr {
    border-spacing: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
td {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
th {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[dpieagent_iecontroltype="2"] {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color: #000;
}
input[type="text"] {
    text-indent: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color: #000;
}
input[type="password"] {
    text-indent: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color: #000;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color: #000;
    font-family: containfont, Tahoma, Arial;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
input[type="reset"] {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    font-family: containfont, Tahoma, Arial;
    border-color: #000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
input[type="button"] {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color: #000;
}
select {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color: #000;
    font-family: "containfont", Tahoma, Arial;
}
#exit {
    background-color: #FF4040;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#exit:hover {
    background-color: #FF8040;
    color: #000 !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 740px) {
   /*#logo {
       margin: 0 auto;
   }
   */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {
    #header {
        font-family: headfont;
        font-weight: bold;
   }
    #header font {
       /*size: 26px;
       */
        font-size: 26px;
        color: #00ffff;
        font-weight: bold;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
   /*#logo {
       margin: 0 auto;
   }
   */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #footerbg {
        margin-top: 10px;
        height: 200px;
   }
    #footer {
        margin-top: -250px;
        height: 250px;
        min-height: 250px;
   }
    #tblfooternormal {
        display: none;
   }
    #tblfooterrespons {
        margin-right: 35px;
        display: inherit;
   }
}
/* !*responsive css*! //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 570px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 570px) {
    #header {
        font-family: headfont;
        font-weight: bold;
   }
    #header font {
       /*size: 26px;
       */
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #ec4b3f;
        font-weight: bold;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 900px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
   }
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
   }
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
        background-color: #FF8080;
   }
    #topmenu {
        padding-top: 5em;
        max-height: 15px;
        min-height: 15px;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-right: 0em;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
   }
    #topmenu li {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        max-width: 125px;
   }
    #topmenu li a {
        padding: 7px 18px;
        background-color: #990099;
        font-size: 10px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
   }
    #topmenu li {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        min-width: 60px;
   }
    #topmenu li a {
        font-size: 80%;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
        background-color: #ec4b3f;
   }
    #topmenu {
        padding-top: 8em;
        max-height: 11px;
        min-height: 11px;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-right: 0em;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
   }
    #topmenu li {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        max-width: 90px;
   }
    #topmenu li a {
        padding: 3px 3px;
        background-color: #72F96A;
        font-size: 7px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 300px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
   }
    #header {
        font-family: headfont;
        font-weight: bold;
   }
    #header font {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #00ffff;
        font-weight: bold;
   }
    #topmenu {
        padding-top: 5em;
        max-height: 9px;
        min-height: 9px;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-right: 0em;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
   }
    #topmenu li {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        max-width: 70px;
   }
    #topmenu li a {
        padding: 2px 5px;
        background-color: #ec4b3f;
        font-size: 5px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 200px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 200px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 100px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 100px) {
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 210px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 90%;
   }
    #maintext {
        padding-right: 0%;
        max-width: 90%;
   }
    p {
        max-width: 80%;
   }
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=4">
      <title>registering system</title>
      <link href="style-en.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="ref/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="">
      <div id="top">
         <div class="topmenu" id="topmenu">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.php" class='lia'>Main Page</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.php?click=ln">Sign in</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.php?click=contact">contact us</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.php?click=req">request</a></li>
               <br>
               <li><a href="index.php?click=regp">register person</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.php?click=regc">register in classes</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.php?click=lp">List of persons</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.php?click=lc"></a>List of classes</li>
               <li><a id="logout" href="index.php?click=logout">logout</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="header" style=" background-color:#003;opacity:0.6;text-align: center">
            <font>
            Registering System Of Education Center
            </font>
         </div>
         <div class="logo" id="logo1" align="center">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="wrap">
         <div id="spacer"></div>
         <div style="height:100px;"></div>
         <div id="main" align="right">
            <a name="bl1"></a>
            <div id="spacer"></div>
            <div id="maintext">
               <p style="width:700px"><strong style="font-size:24px">Information:</strong><br />This is main page...</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
         <div id="footerbg" style=" background-color:#003;opacity:0.6;">
         </div>
         <div id="info">
            <table id="tblfooternormal" style="bottom:0px;right:0;min-width:700px;">
               <tr>
                  <td width="25px"></td>
                  <td>
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:100px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:100px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:100px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:100px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                  </td>
                  <td> <img src="img/telegram.png" width="50px" height="50px" style=" clear:left;
                     float:right;margin-left:20px; " />
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>Our channel:</b></font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b><a href="http://#" target="_blank"
                        style="text-decoration: none;color:#09C;" >####</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font><br />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px
                        solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px
                        solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>Address:</b></font><br /><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>Tel:</b></font><br />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px
                        solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px
                        solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>Wrb design department</b></font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>History:</b></font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>.................</b></font><br />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" style="height:50px;width:2px;border-right:1px solid;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////responsive table//////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
            <table id="tblfooterrespons" style="bottom:0px;right:10px;width: 70%;">
               <tr style="width: 50%">
                  <td>
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>Wrb design department</b></font><br />
                     <img src="img/telegram.png" width="50px" height="50px" style=" clear:left;
                        float:right;margin-left:20px; " />
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>Our channel:</b></font><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b><a href="http://#" target="_blank"
                        style="text-decoration: none;color:#09C;" >###</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font><br />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <hr color="#00CC66">
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>Address:</b></font><br /><br />
                     <font color="#00CC66" id="down"><b>Tel:</b></font><br />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <hr color="#00CC66">
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you mean there is a negative value in the footer ,this is for in order to has always placed exactly at the bottom of the page and not higher up and not be outside the scope of View

Comment: What about the footer, i cant understand or is this relevant to this post?? I didnt add or change any of the code her.

Comment: Excuse me ,my reply sent to you by mistake and I did not give that negative point to your answer. Your answer is good and it works fine.thanks but I can use !importan to apply some media queries.I give you a positive point

Comment: Thank you, but if you use !important on lets say 400 width your 300 wont work.